# ODBC Connection String error - C#

Tags: c#, odbc, quickbooks, unhandled-exception

Attempting a simple ODBC connection to QuickBooks 2017 and have been unable to connect.

This is my current(among many other attempts) connection string.
[connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwiH4.jpg)

This is OdbcException was unhandled error
[unhandled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tyK2.jpg)

Error Message:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Any input on where I'm going wrong is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Look at control panel : Admin Tools : Data Source (ODBC).  Something is wrong with the driver specified in the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good [site](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2347/49/qodbc-desktop--how-do-i-build-a-connection-string-with-all-the-available-qodbc-parameters--connection-string-with-qodbc-parameters) , where you can find help

Long story short,

**Example of simple DSN**

```
sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"
```

**Example of a DSNless connection string**

```
sConnectString = "Driver={QODBC Driver for QuickBooks};DFQ=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Sample Company Files\QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0\sample_service-based business.qbw;OpenMode=M;OLE DB Services=-2;"
```

**Example of using current ADO syntax**

```
sConnectString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=QuickBooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"
```

**Standard syntax**

```
"DRIVER={QODBC Driver for QuickBooks};SERVER=QODBC;DFQ=.;OLE DB Services=-2;OptimizerOn=No;"
```